# Web Service is not returning JSON

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, web-services, web

I know many times this question has been posted over here. But i am not able to find solution for my problem.

I have create one web service and i have set method return type as JSON but method still returns XML.

Here is my method :

```
[WebMethod(Description = "LoginMethod")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string doLogin(string UserName, string Password)
{
         LoginSuccess objSuccess = new LoginSuccess();
         UserInfo objInfo = new UserInfo();
         objSuccess.success = "true";
         objInfo.Token = "token";
         objInfo.type = "usertype";
         objInfo.username = "username";
         objInfo.userid = "userid";
         objSuccess.response = objInfo;
         clsJSON objJSON = new clsJSON();
         loginResponse = objJSON.ToJSON(objSuccess);
         return loginResponse;
}
```

Here is my response :

```
<string>{"success":"true","response":{"Token":"token","username":"username","userid":"userid","type":"usertype"}}</string>
```

But i want this as :

```
{"success":"true","response":{"Token":"token","username":"username","userid":"userid","type":"usertype"}}
```

I am calling this method from that page which web service giving us to test method. Request method is HttpPost.

Please suggest me for this.

Comment: It's never a bad idea to specify which language and frameworks you're using in your tags. You should also include your javascript code since it's part of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've either not specified or used the wrong accept request header. It should be `application/json`. Without the relevant javascript code used to fetch data in your question it's not possible to say what exactly you should put where though.

Comment: Thanks for your great reply i am using .net 4.0 and in that i am using test page which .net 4.0 provides to test web service. After your reply i check for request type is application/xml now i want to change request type to application/json. Is it possible in that page to change request type

Comment: @Anvesh: Yes it's possible. How you do it depend on whether you're using a javascript framework or creating XMLHttpRequest objects for different browsers yourself.

Comment: By using javascript i set application/json and i got response in json but if i test from that page which .net is giving to test web service method it always send application/xml request i want to change it to application/json. Is there any way to change that page' request type? B'caz i am not able to find any code for that page.

Comment: @Anvesh: Is that a page generated by your IDE? If so, are you using Visual Studio or something else?

Comment: it's generated by IDE and i am using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: @Anvesh: Then you're out of luck. Unfortunately the "Add Web Reference" wizard, which I assume you're using, doesn't support json.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5584/discussion-between-anvesh-and-flesk)